# Layout issues after updating to Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode8, ios10

Here is a before and after of one of my screens after I upgraded to Xcode 8.
All I did was open up my *main.storyboard* and from there, I built and ran my app on my phone.
In my version control, I can see Xcode is doing a lot of changes to my main.storyboard just from me opening it. 
Whenever I delete those changes, I can see what I use to see in Xcode 7.3.1.
But, as soon as I re-open interface builder with my storyboard, I see those changes come back into place.
  Is there something I can do here?

### Before Xcode 8

[image]

### After update to Xcode 8

[image]

Comment: Try opening up XCode 8 again with a fresh source (stash any changes it's made previously). Now, when you open up the storyboard, highlight all of your UI items and click "Update Frames". This might fix your problem.

Comment: Could you file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach the storyboard for which this is happening? We would like to analyze this further.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. After opening my storyboard in Xcode8 and accepting the "Choose an initial device view" Dialog, everyting is acting strange. When I update all frames, the IB looks good, but after building, the app is totally broken. Tested it with 4 apps.

Comment: @QuinnTaylor I'm having a similar problem, after Xcode 8 converts my storyboard the UIImageViews in UITableViews do not show any content although their outline is visible in `Debug View Hierarchy`. Other objects of the same class that are in UICollectionViews are not the affected.

Comment: XIB or Storyboard set default as older version 7.x and Save and Close. Temporary solution, but works. Don't open again once you have done Save and Close. Otherwise again need follow same steps from begin.

Comment: My Autolayout is totally broken in storyboards  , I don't even sure what to do .

Comment: This appears to be fixed as of Xcode 8 beta 3 (according to the release notes it's fixed in beta 2 but I haven't verified that).

Comment: @QuinnTaylor our app, with a massive user base, has this issue in the new version we released yesterday.  For some reason, it only exists on my environment, but my coworkers don't have this issue on their versions of xcode8.0.  We resubmitted and put in an expedite request with the fix.  This created significant issues for our users- they weren't able to view their security cameras!  Is there a fix for this in a version of xcode that can be used to deploy to the app store? (beta versions can't be used to deploy)  If not, I can't push updates to the app store from my computer!

Comment: I have backup, So, I just open my backup in Xcode 7.3 open Storyboard as Source code copy and paste it in my latest code. That's It. It work for me.

Answer (score 111):

I had a similar problem with tableview images not appearing once I converted the storyboard file to be Xcode8 compatible. This looks like a bug with Xcode8, so until a bug fix is released, here is a work around:

1. Open your storyboard in Xcode 8 and choose an initial device view. Make changes as you normally would.
2. Once you have completed your changes, select the storyboard -> File Inspector -> Opens in -> Select 'Xcode 7.x'.

[image]

3. Select 'Save and Close' when prompted
4. Your storyboard changes will be saved, and your storyboard will function as it did pre-Xcode8.

When you need to make other changes to the storyboard file, follow these steps again.

Comment: Wow +1 for this for sure. I struggled with this in iOS 10 within my TodayExtension. It wasn't until I narrowed things down, analyzing the git diffs, that I saw suspect storyboard xml edits being added by Xcode 8. After saving the storyboard document for Xcode 7 (after making my edits), I can now build and ship using Xcode 8 for iOS 10. Thanks.

Comment: It sure looks a bug. Saving as Opens in Xcode 7.x worked for me as a temporary workaround.

Comment: i spent past 3 days on fixing all the broken layout from place to place in Xcode8 until i found this post. i probably should trust people like you guys more than Apple. can't believe this wasted so much of my time. Thank you very much David for this!

Comment: @XuYin Should we do this for every storyboard? I mean what if I have another storyboard in my project? What about Xib files? should I do it for those as well?

Comment: @Honey i didn't do that on storyboard, but i did on every xib file that i have issue with. but i think you might want to try it on storyboard as well if you see strange layout issue. since that fix will only take like 5 seconds. and after rebuild the app, you should be able to see the fix very quickly.

Comment: well if you have a huge project this could be tiresome, aside from that I'm not sure if Apple won't fix the issue itself or not and later we would have to undo what we did

Comment: I have the same issue. But this solution is not working for me. :(

Comment: This doesn't help because I need to work on the file. All this does is save the file for backwards compatibility. It doesn't allow the xib to be edited in Xcode 8.

Comment: @jowie You can still work on the file and make changes to the storyboard file. Just make sure you follow Step 2 when you've finished making your changes.

Comment: @DavidTruong It's a XIB file not a storyboard, but I can't make changes to the initial file because all the layout is broken and "update frames" is greyed out. I need to work on the file as it was in Xcode 7, but it won't let me.

Comment: I did this changes following the steps but when I open it on xCode 7 the screen size of each viewcontroller in the storyboard is wrong, the size & form factor is 3,5" instead 4".

Comment: Solution works out for me, but anyone knows what Apple thinks about that? is there any official bug report?

Comment: This works for me. Hopefully Apple fixes this soon. I can live with the issue for now and I only need to set the option back to Xcode 7 when distributing or giving a demo. It can stay at 8 while developing

Comment: Is incredible, why XCode 8 has to do this?? After updating to XCode 8 and have to choose an intial view for only watching my XIBs, almost all of my views were messed up. This is the solution that works for me, having to save all of them with Open in XCode 7.

Comment: Not working too. Xcode 8 is always asking to convert or exit :(

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Whenever I try to switch to the Xcode 7 layout, I save & close, but when I open my storyboard again it says "Choose an initial review view" and after choosing a view it automatically switches back to the Xcode 8 option.. how could I solve this ?

Comment: I tried this method on my storyboard but i didn't find any changes. My views are missing.

Comment: After change `latest Xcode` to `7.x` and then choose `Choose an initial device view` then Xcode auto switch `latest Xcode` to `8.0` again. Anyone have the same problem, please help me?

Answer (score 14):

XIB or Storyboard set default as older version 7.x and Save and Close. Temporary solution, but works. Don't open again once you have done Save and Close. Otherwise again need follow same steps from begin.[image]

Comment: This doesn't help because I need to work on the file. All this does is save the file for backwards compatibility. It doesn't allow the xib to be edited in Xcode 8.

Comment: i am doing this but again when i am selecting xib file in dropdown  it is showing xcode 8.0 only...

Answer (score 8):

Eh the same problem. I partially managed to fix it in the following way (*for Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62)*)

In the document outline of Storyboard, I clicked on each scene which had the yellow arrow indicating some layout issues (Number 1 on the screenshot)

After this, for each problematic scene, I had to click on "Update Frames" small icon (Number 2 on the screenshot) which fixed all the layout issues per scene.

[image]

However one scene in my case was still in crying state after transition from Xcode7 to Xcode8. I had to fix it manually by adjusting constraints or adding missing constraints.

Phew, not nice surprise of XCode8 and Storyboards. If you used AppCode editor, you won't have such problem, since it doesn't support Storyboards ;P

Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

Xcode 8.1 Beta 2 resolves this issue. Please check this download link

https://developer.apple.com/download/

Comment: I dont think so... :(

Comment: Xcode 8.3.2 get the same issue. Fck Xcode and Apple :(

Answer (score 6):

Please follow the threads for any possible solution:(I believe it happens to many developers).
[Xcode 8 GM seed Storyboard issue](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62313)
[Xcode 8 - Previous storyboards getting distorted](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/179611#179611)

(I used anyH anyW width 600) When Xcode updated to Xcode 8 it changed all my ViewControllers size. As a result all the layout was distorted.
Currently I see only 3 solution for the issue (I wouldn't trust on waiting for fix soon).

1.Go for each  Viewcontroller and fix it it by `Update Frames`.
   2.Go to the main ViewController `Size Inspector  -> Freeform -> 600` as most of the controllers are inferred it will change the size for
   all of them.(Be careful on the impact of  new Features Apple my want
   to introduce).
   3.Discard the changes in git for the storyboard (I would't suggest it because Apple also inserted some updates which may be important to
   Xcode).

Additional link  for the new AutoLayout features in Xcode 8 (WWDC16):
[Making Apps Adaptive, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/)

Comment: Option 1 is the most sensible and it worked for me. As Mike.R notes, be careful of trying to 'trick' XCode into fixing things as more trouble down the track is inevitable.

Comment: I used option 1 as well (I think its more safe). But its time consuming.

Answer (score 5):

In my case works solutions suggested by Akhil Kateja and I also need to reset Width and Height of the main view:

**1) Set View Size to Free Form**

[image]

**2) Reset Width and Height of the view to the original size:**

[image]

Finally save and you are done.

Answer (score 4):

For me the solution was simply to click on the UIViewController having issues and then `Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > All Views In ... > Updates Frames`

It re-arranged the views to fit the existing constraints based on the newly selected default view (iPhone 7 in my case).

Also note: if you get a **Navigation Bar Misplaced View** warning like I did, simply select the UINavigationController/UIViewController and then `Attributes Inspector > Bar Visibility > Shows Navigation Bar` - toggle it OFF and then ON again.

Answer (score 3):

Setting View Size to *Freeform* from *Inferred* worked for me. It can be found under the heading *Simulated Metrics* in *Attributes Inspector*.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I've solved it by force update the controller's view constraints. Put the following code in your **viewDidLoad()** function

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Cheers Bill! that 'layoutIfNeeded' worked for me! (After trying everything else for hours..)

Answer (score 3):

I selected each controller and clicked on "Update Frames" and it fixed the layout.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @david-truong (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39589860/1407528) is not working in my case, so if you are in my same situation, try this:

- Download the previous Xcode 7.3.1 from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
- Undo all your changes (if you have a code manager like git. If you don't, you should 'https://githowto.com/')
- Open the project with Xcode 7.3.1.

In the case you have all your devices updated to iOS 10+, this version of Xcode will not recognize those devices as compatible devices. So, try with this trick:

- Go to: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
- Copy the folders related with iOS 10 or 10.1 to: /Applications/Xcode 7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
- Open the project with Xcode 7.3.1 (restart Xcode if you have it already opened)
- Select your connected iOS 10+ device
- Push Run

Note: New features like Swift will not be available using this trick, but you should be able to load and build your project.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help

When i updated Xcode from 7.3 to Xcode 8 and run the app, some of the views are perfectly displayed but some are distorted.Then, i checked the nib file and it prompted me to choose particular device size and then show the nib according to that device size which is offcourse not `Any-Any(Xcode 7.3)`. So all the nibs file are not displaying in a correct way.

Solution work form me :- press the yellow arrow like showing in image below

[image]

it will prompt a pop up which show options  like

[image]

choose `Update Frames` with `Apply to all views in container` checked.it will solved around 90% of distorted UI and rest of the auto-layout constraints problem can be solved manually.

Comment: This might also spoil Layouts. IMHO this has to be done with much care, one view at a time and checking if things worked out before continuing.

Comment: yes, off-course you need to consume some time for it and this solution might help you in a longer run as when you want to update some of ur UI.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue using the Xcode Version 7.3.1 you can download the .dmg file from apple developer portal. I used the Autoresizing in every app and it works great for me.
i will update to Xcode 8 only if they can fix this bug.

Download it here: https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3.1/Xcode_7.3.1.dmg

Comment: This solution is useless if you want to support iOS 10

Answer (score 1):

To fix a similar problem, I configured the xib as Freeform (not Inferred) AND saved xib file as Xcode 7.x compatible. Both steps were required in my case. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I notice one new button in Xcode 8.2, (check the orange circle in the image). It will give you some help.

Steps:
 1. Open the storyboard and select any device you want
 2. Just select the View Controller
 3. Click the mentioned button (as in Image)
 4. It will updates the frame for that view controller and you can proceed with it

I didn't found any better solution than this. Please reply if found one.

[image: IB screenshot]

Comment: Nothing got happen.

Answer (score 0):

update constraints and layout subviews in viewdidload solves the problem

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
        [self.view updateConstraints];
        [self.view layoutSubviews];
        [super viewDidLoad];
}
```