# XCode 8 interface builder problems?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have a very strange problems with `Interface Builder` in XCode 8 (final, not beta). First, the width and height of ALL my `UIViewControllers` in the project is changed, but the size of all controls (subviews) remain the same. I suppose this happened when I upgraded the project and `Open in Latest Xcode (8.0) and Deployment Target (8.3)` settings were set.

Also, today I get a lot of warnings and 1 error in the same designer which yesterday works fine, even in the forms that I did not change.

So it this a bug, and how to return forms to previous state, without manually change each one of them?

Comment: can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, no solution. I just wanted to tell you that I have many problems with IB in Xcode 8. Feels like an early beta rather than a final version.

Comment: 10x @dasdom. I suspect that. I fix the second error by restoring backup from yesterday, but I want to be sure that I am not making any mistake. We hope those issues will be fixed in 8.1.

Comment: Duplicated of? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497572/layout-issues-after-updating-to-xcode-8

Comment: The exact same thing happened to my projects, I still don't have a solution if not to manually move everything back to place.

Comment: Sorry @LucasC.Feijo, as far as I know, no. I have backup.