# After Xcode Update my Xib files loss all alignments

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xib

Hi last week I updated my mac book and xcode now when I open my old application and modify xib file after saving I loss all alignments , I try to Undo changes but still not working .but when I put old xib file from backup it becomes as before.

Now I need to modify how can I do that.

Comment: there is no way to revert this alignments.request to all please keep backup of your project.

Comment: Thanks seggy  I have a backup that saves me

Comment: found temporary work around  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39589860/1058346