# Unable to boot iOS simulator in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

[image]

I have tried all the solutions which found on stack overflow, but still not able to resolve it. Somehow its not open the simulator and gives me error **unable to boot simulator**.

I have reinstall 2 times `Xcode` and reset simulator content and Settings Several times. But i'm not able to get any solution.

Comment: have you try to restart your computer?

Comment: @Wos Yes, I restart my computer.

Comment: This happened to me on Xcode 8 from 18 Oct 2016 onwards. Until then everything was fine. Also get the Coretelephony  trace file error on mac os startup.

Comment: I was facing the same issue with Xcode 8. Still not fixed :(

Comment: which version of mac os x?

Comment: I had the same issue then I keep on closing and opening the simulator for three to four times and its working fine now.

Comment: @RohanBhale I updated my Xcode with 8 , but i faced UI issues  and not able to get any solution so i uninstall Xcode 8 and reinstall 7.3.

Comment: @Wos OS X Ei Capitan version 10.11.6

Comment: can you share your screen shot for more investigation

Comment: @Merry Please check this link for UI issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497572/layout-issues-after-updating-to-xcode-8/39954298#39954298. Don't downgrade to 7.3

Comment: @Manigandasaravanan I know this solution but i'm not using auto layout in my project . And also it's a temporary solution for Xcode 8.0.

Comment: does you project build without error? or did you get any error message in the console?

Comment: @Enix No, i'm not getting any error while build project.

Comment: What is the exact error message indicated in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log at the time of the failure?

Comment: Also based on an answer in a related question (which I find suspicious), what is the output of `stat /private/tmp`

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue many times and the only solution for now is to reinstall Mac OS and then install xcode 7.3 stable version . this will definitely solve your problems.

Comment: Which version of Mac you are using

Comment: OS X EI Capitan version:10.11.6 (15G1004)

Comment: Install OS x El Sierra instead of  OS X EI Capitan ..

I was also having the issue in CAptain but when i install Sierra then my issue was fixed .

Comment: Finally app is running in simulator . Thank you :)