# Xcode 8 - changes in constraints is not taking effect in preview

Tags: ios, autolayout, swift3, xcode8

I've just upgraded to xcode 8 swift 3 and the whole layout of my project is a mess. I'm trying to change constraints but is not taking effect in preview like last version. I've follewed the same procedure I've used to Xcode 7.3. Are there something new that I don't know ?

Comment: How did you check the preview ? Are you using the new preview option provided in the Xcode 8 ?

Comment: I'm not with my laptop now but I'll try to explain what I do. I click on the double circle and in main.strory (preview). So I see the preview of my layout but I change all constraints or click to add automatically and the preview is having no effect.

Comment: The changes you make in constraint won't affect the preview page, you need to close and open the preview pane again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching I found that this a bug. This workaround solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/39653512/2238515 my issue. On the other hand is waiting for an update from Apple

Answer (score 0):

You might have to update frame. If when you modify in preview you see a yellow arrow next to the view then "Update Frame"

[image]

Comment: I know about Update Frames but It's not the case. I tried this too.