# How to ReInstall Podfile in the project?

Tags: ios, podfile

I have downgrade my operating system from Mac Os Sierra to el Capitan, so all the files were removed from my system,but i have done backup my project.
Now when i have opened my project for running .Workspace file it shows me empty in my project. 
So please tell me i have used google places api in the project but  project is  not working . 
I have done pod installation then this error is coming when i click on Main.Storyboard.
What to do
[image]

Please help me what to do?

Comment: Run `pod install`

Comment: @rmaddy when i am using this then it shows error pod install
-bash: pod: command not found

Comment: Install cocoa pods.

Comment: after Install Cocoapods , i will run pod install?@rmaddy

Comment: You've done this all before. Read the instructions.

Comment: Before that maybe you need to reinstall Command line tools.
`xcode-select --install`

Comment: @rmaddy please help me in this error , i have updated my question

Comment: If you opened your project in XCode8.0. You can't able to access it in XCode 7.0 or lower. You should upgrade your Machine to Sierra and XCode to 8.0 or 8.1 beta.

Comment: @Manigandasaravanan i have dowloaded sierra and xcode 8 but my project totally distorted and not working properly ,therefore i downgrade the os to el capitan, now what to do please give me any solution

Comment: What kind of distortion you are facing in XCode 8?

Comment: If you are facing UI issues try using XCode 8.1 beta 2. They resolved it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497572/layout-issues-after-updating-to-xcode-8/39954298#39954298

Answer (score 37):

```
pod deintegrate
```

Then

```
pod install
```

Answer (score -2):

Just need to reinstall Xcode 8 from the app store and then go to the project and select Xcode 7 [image: xcodeImage]

The problem is that in Xcode 8, they changed the format of the story board which is not compatible with Xcode 7. Another option is to undo the changes to the storyboard if you've used VCS (which I hope you are)