# Issue in Xcode 8.1 Storyboard layouts

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10

After update Xcode 8.1 why the storyboard don't show any layouts. Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: Just restart your PC and Xcode (Force Quit). You get your UI back.

Comment: Try this . it is working on my xcode: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39589860/3901620

Comment: @AshishKakkad Thanks a lot bro. you saved my time. It worked.

Comment: Just change the size class, some time it gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can always uncheck it

In the top menu -> Editor -> Canvas -> Show Bounds Rectangles

[image]

Comment: blue border is gone but it still doesn't show any controls on view controller.