# Xcode 8.1 view control bug?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm very new to Xcode and I am trying to make a very simple view app like Hello Wolrd with button and label.

But when I'm in the main.storyboard editor, I can put button and label, but they do not show up. They do when I move them, but once placed they only the selection rectangle.

I can still use them in the viewcontroller.swift and it works perfectly in the simulator.

I don't have this problem when I open a project for macOS.

I tried some solutions I found her but they does not seem to fix the issue.

[Issue in Xcode 8.1 Storyboard layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40422297/issue-in-xcode-8-1-storyboard-layouts)

[Layout issues after updating to Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497572/layout-issues-after-updating-to-xcode-8/39589860#39589860)

Is it another Xcode 8.1 bug ? Or is there something I do wrong ?

Thanks !!

edit : some captures pictures

[When moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/box4C.jpg)

[When placed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTB5g.jpg)

Comment: try setting dark background colour to your viewController this way you may see the button/label and  autoConstraints to your label and button ...

Comment: Well, the viewController doesn't change its background color either...

Comment: These is no Xcode bug in your case.problem may be you didn't set the mainStoryBoard class or IBOutlet issue.check again or start all over again with the new project....