# XCode 8.1 Changed Constants in Storyboard Views

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xcode8

When I updated to XCode 8.1, it changed the constants for many of my constraints in my Storyboard and left it in a jumbled mess.  I read in another post that the next XCode beta might fix it and am downloading it to try.  It's a good sized storyboard and I would prefer not to have to redo all the constraints.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Xcode(8.1) has fixed this issues. This was a known issue in Xcode 8.0.

I have not used Xcode 8.2 but if you are facing issues you might want to stick to 8.1. You can refer here as well: -

[Layout issues after updating to Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497572/layout-issues-after-updating-to-xcode-8)

Following is taken from Xcode 8.1 release [notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html):

**Interface Builder**

**New Features**

- Added Custom Gesture Recognizer to the object library. Use it for custom subclasses of UIGestureRecognizer or NSGestureRecognizer instead of a plain NSObject. This resolves an issue where a combination of stock and custom gesture recognizers on a UIView fails to compile. (27838954)
- There is a new Update Frames button at the bottom of the canvas. Click the button to update the frames of the selected objects and their children on the Interface Builder canvas. (27818991)
- The Pin button at the bottom of the canvas has been renamed to Add New Constraints. (27819014)

**Resolved Issues**

- Dragging content into static UITableView cell on the canvas works again. (28026179)
- > Fixed auto layout performance issue with NSStackView using Gravity
  >   Areas distribution. (27910320)
- Xcode 8.0 did not always restore view frames from storyboards and xibs when layouts were ambiguous. Xcode 8.1 fixes several of these issues. If you have encountered these issues, resolve the ambiguity in the Auto Layout issues and update frames. Xcode 8.1 will persist them correctly. (28221021, 28244619)
- Resolved a layout hang when selecting Landscape orientation in the Device Bar on non-Retina displays when running on OS X 10.11. (27251685)
- Xcode Debug Console no longer shows extra logging from system frameworks when debugging applications in the Simulator. (26652255, 27331147)
- When using Swift 2.3, creating IBAction connections no longer inserts WithSender in the selector name. (25220368)

Comment: Thanks! Strangely I'm having the issue while using XCode 8.1.  I'll follow the steps and check it out

Comment: @MatthewDiMarcantonio Sure. Let me know if you have any issue.